# Delegate protocol/IBOutlet

Tags: ios, iboutlet, delegation

I basically have a subclass (RRView) of UIView with a delegate protocol. The RRViews are connected via outlets to the view controller which implements the delegate protocol as well as  the delegates.

The code where I ask the delegate for additional info is implemented like this.

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<RRViewDelegate>)delegate {
  if (_delegate != delegate) {
    _delegate = delegate;

    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cornersForRRView:)]) {
        self.corners = [_delegate cornersForRRView:self];
    }

    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cornerRadiusForRRView:)]) {
        CGFloat maxRadius = floorf(self.bounds.size.height/2);
        CGFloat radius = [_delegate cornerRadiusForRRView:self];
        self.cornerRadius = MIN(radius, maxRadius);
    }

    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(rotationTypeForRRView:)]) {
        self.type = [_delegate rotationTypeForRRView:self];
    }

    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(fontSizeForRRView:)]) {
        self.fontSize = [_delegate fontSizeForRRView:self];
        self.textFont = [UIFont fontWithName:self.textFont.fontName size:self.fontSize];
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I face is that I have a bunch of RRViews so I try to distinguish them like so, but the outlets are not yet connected.

```
- (UIRectCorner)cornersForRRView:(RRView *)view  {
  if ([view isEqual:self.dimensionsInfoView]) {
    return UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight;
  }
  else if ([view isEqual:self.oneHundredPercentInfoView]) {
    return UIRectCornerTopRight;
  }
  else if ([view isEqual:self.deviceApperanceInfoView]) {
    return UIRectCornerTopLeft;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
 }
```

}

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: So the issue is that in your delegate callback methods, the if-statements are basically all `if ([view isEqual:nil])` because the self.outletVars aren't connected?  If that's the case, it it an issue of running the code before they're connected (say in `init:` vs `viewDidLoad`), or some other reason?

Comment: As everything is done in IB it is rather an issue of order. I guess (and that sounds logical to me) initialization walks up the hierarchy when connecting outlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can safely use pointer comparison here - `view == self.dimensionsInfoView` instead of `[view isEqual:self.dimensionsInfoView]`. You want to check whether the references contain the same objects, not check the internal states of the objects.

Also, you don't have to check if delegate is `nil` (`_delegate &&`), this is not Java, calling a method on `nil` delegate will just return `NO`.

The anwer for you question is rather simple.

**Option 1:** Don't set the delegate in xib, set it in controller's `viewDidLoad`, when the `IBOutlets` are already connected.

**Option 2:** Don't call the delegate methods in `setDelegate`, call them in some other method, e.g. `[UIView layoutSubviews]`.

**Option 3:** Drop the setup methods from the delegate and call them directly in `viewDidLoad`, e.g. `[self.dimensionsInfoView setFontSize:10.0f]`, `[self.dimensionsInfoView setCorners:... withRadius:...]`;

I would definitely go with Option 3. You are just overcomplicate matters with a delegate. Why calling delegate methods for something that doesn't change?

Comment: Option 3 was what I did before. I was looking for a more elegant way of customizing as RRView grew over time to a multifunctional ... (you know what I mean) beast with lots of features. Thanks for all the other hints as well. I think the best way is to have a general setup method in RRView which makes the delegate calls. This way I can control when initialization should take place and I can stick with delegation.

Comment: @BerndRabe There is a reason why you should stick with Option 3 - simplicity. Setting up your views using a delegate is... strange and doesn't have any benefits. Imagine a `UIButton` being set up this way, with delegate methods to return font, text and images. Keep things at once place instead of distributing them up into many delegate methods.

Comment: I totally agree. Option 3 is the least error prone one. Though it is the one where you might have to write more code (as in my case, where can configure anchorPoints for rotation, shape layer border colors etc.). As I have both ways implemented I have now to options.